# Can't remove old hard drive without getting no bootable devices found message

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd, operating-systems

I have my OS installed on an SSD, and a 2 tb hard drive in my PC that I primarily use, but I left my old 500 gb hdd in there, and unless it's in my system I get an error saying no bootable devices found.

My SSD has windows installed, but whenever booting it it shows a bootloader, would that have anything to do with it?  I've checked the bios and the boot devices, and nothing is seeming to work

Comment: Run `diskmgmt.msc` (Disk Management) and mark as active partition on your SSD drive where Status contains "System".

Answer (score 0):

Although your OS is installed on an SSD it can not boot independantly because it relies on the bootloader which seems to be located on your 500GB drive.

If you disconnect all your drives except for the SSD and start an attempt to repair the booting ability using your OS installation media you might be able to boot independantly afterwards.